# Tag for printed interactive fiction books (gamebooks, choose your own adventure books)

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we have a tag for printed interactive fiction books (gamebooks, choose your own adventure books, not requiring a computer)?  If we do, tag [Trying to find book I read from library about a lone person crash landing on an alien planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87405/4918) .  If we don't, what should we call it?

This would be simlar to other media type tags like [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel), [short-story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story), [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) [film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film), [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) etc, and would help the most for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions to help search for other questions that may ask for the same work.

More such questions I found:

- [Clock Embeded in Eyelid. Choose Your Own Adventure(?)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55157/4918)
- [Story/book identification - Star Wars Choose Your Own Adventure, fighting Boba Fett](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/51157/4918)
- [Adventure book, possibly published around 25 years ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33204/4918)
- [Book Identification: Stuck in a Store after Closing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22522/4918)
- [Drawing of Yggdrasil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31908/4918)
- [Identify a short story where a young boy is time-shifted several minutes into the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21356/4918) (original poster identifies it as interactive fiction book in answer)
- [Series following a lone adventurer named Grey Wolf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40259/4918) (may be interactive fiction if bert's answer is correct)

Plus there's a couple of non-story-id questions about the Lone Wolf series:

- [In Lone Wolf, why does 7 and 13 signify everlasting death in life, and evil power respectively?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65687/4918) (not story-id)
- [Any idea how to get hold of copies of the Legends of Lone Wolf Novels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39426/4918)

Comment: Do we really need it? I would think story-id + book would be enough.

Comment: Yes.  "book" is really common, lots of story-id questions on our site are asking about books. Printed interactive fiction has a lot of different names (that poster didn't even give any common name) so it's hard to search for any keyword (as opposed to, say, Dumbledore who is almost always called that, so you can just search for his name).

Comment: But on the other hand, interactive fiction seems too specific. I've been a member for 9 months now and the linked question is the first one I've seen about interactive fiction. Of course, I might have missed a few but such questions seem pretty rare.

Comment: @Null: there's more such questions, I've edited some into the post, and those are just what I could find easier

Comment: Fair enough, this would probably be a good tag to have then.

Comment: FWIW, [visual novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_novel) is the Japanese term for works along these lines.

Comment: We already have a [choose-your-own-adventure](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choose-your-own-adventure) tag; are there kinds of gamebooks that wouldn't fall under that category? RPG gamebooks spring to mind, but do we have any story-id questions about them?

Comment: @Jas Yes, that tag should work.

Answer (score 5):

We already have [choose-your-own-adventure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choose-your-own-adventure). I've gone ahead and added it to three of the linked questions:

- [Trying to find book I read from library about a lone person crash landing on an alien planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/trying-to-find-book-i-read-from-library-about-a-lone-person-crash-landing-on-an)
- [Adventure book, possibly published around 25 years ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/adventure-book-possibly-published-around-25-years-ago)
- [Identify a short story where a young boy is time-shifted several minutes into the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21356/identify-a-short-story-where-a-young-boy-is-time-shifted-several-minutes-into-th)

Some of the linked questions already had the tag:

- [Clock Embeded in Eyelid. Choose Your Own Adventure(?)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55157/clock-embeded-in-eyelid-choose-your-own-adventure)
- [Story/book identification - Star Wars Choose Your Own Adventure, fighting Boba Fett](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51157/story-book-identification-star-wars-choose-your-own-adventure-fighting-boba-f)
- [Book Identification: Stuck in a Store after Closing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22522/book-identification-stuck-in-a-store-after-closing)

But the others I'm not confident if the tag should be added; not confident enough to edit, anyway:

- The OP of [Drawing of Yggdrasil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/drawing-of-yggdrasil) does specifically call out a CYOA book, but only to point out what their desired book *isn't* I don't see anything else in the description to suggest that it's a gamebook
- [Series following a lone adventurer named Grey Wolf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/series-following-a-lone-adventurer-named-grey-wolf) has an accepted answer which is *not* a CYOA book
- I don't know anything about the "Lone Wolf" series, so I don't feel qualified to make the edit here

Answer (score 3):

There is already a [choose-your-own-adventure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choose-your-own-adventure) tag which would seem to cover the majority of these sort of interactive RPG books.

I do appreciate that CYOA is actually a [brand name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choose_Your_Own_Adventure) rather than a catch-all term, but it seems pretty darned close

Comment: I think "Choose your own adventure" is pretty much a [generic trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark) by this point; maybe not in the strictest legal sense, but for all practical purposes

Comment: I shall write a letter (in biro) to the publishers to see if they're happy with that.